# Ionic - How to automatically pause a video within iframe?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have some data that I am getting from an API server, the data contains an **iframe** video that get played automatically, I am trying to pause the video from being played without clicking on it.

This is a vanilla javascript code that I am using:

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (var i = 0; i< frames.length; i++) {
    var innerDoc = (frames.item(i).contentDocument) ? 
        frames.item(i).contentDocument : frames.item(i).contentWindow.document;
    var iframeVideoTags = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("video");
    for (var j = 0; j < iframeVideoTags.length; j++) {
        iframeVideoTags.item(j).pause();
    }
}
```

Inside inspect console, I see this error says:

`VM10923:4 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8100" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: You can't access elements inside iframe. You need to post messages to it. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Inside console after video being loaded, it post a message says: **Video has been loaded** , do you mean i need to post that message ?

Comment: No. On Iframe you should have window.addEventListener("message", (message) => <your code that reacts to incoming messages. i.e. if(message === 'pause'){ video.pause() }>, false);. Then on your parent page you can do frames.item(i).contentWindow.postMessage(<your message, i.e. pause>, "*"); to pause the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code working perfectly since i want to pause it if it loaded automatically then to play it if the user want to play the video.

```
window.addEventListener(
"message",
(message: any) => {
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    if (message.data === "canplay") {
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        try {
        frames.item(i).contentWindow.postMessage("pause", "*");
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        }
    }
    }
},
false
);
```